# calling window.sessionStorage in node js

Tags: node.js

How do I call window.sessionStorage in node js to get values of keys stored in the browser?

Is there an npm module that will allow me to store values in session storage?

Comment: Node runs on backend. You cannot get "browser" session like that on node.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get it directly, but you can send them from browser to node using for example ajax.

```
var sessionData = {};
for(var i = 0; i < window.sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = window.sessionStorage.key(i);
    sessionData[key] = window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://node_server_url/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(sessionData));
```

Now you just need to receive and parse this data using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: you're not sending the values of the session storage keys here only the key name

Comment: Right, it's fixed now